# Failed to concate pointer variables

Tags: c, pointers, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I want to concat two pointer variable. try different apporch but failed, No Resource found - No address found error comes.

FYI: Tizen Wearable SDK 3.0 Samsung Gear S2 watch

Try1:

```
  char *idP;

  //finalFrame is pointer array. 
  //finalFrame is char Array char *finalFrame[25]
  char *id1 = finalFrame[6]; //0
  char *id0 = finalFrame[7]; //3 
  dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "id0 : %d", id0); // output: id1 : 0 
  dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "id1 : %d", id1); // output: id1 : 3 

   if((idP = (char *)malloc(strlen(id0) + strlen(id1) + 1)) != NULL){ // appcrash here
                *idP='\0';
                strcpy(idP, id1);
                strcat(idP, id0);
                dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "-----idP %s",idP);
            }else{
                dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "No memory");
            }
```

Try2:

```
char *idP=concat(id1,id0);

dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "-----id : %s", idP); // but failed

//method
char * concat(char *str1, char *str2) {
char *conc = str1;

while (*str1 != '\0')
    str1++;

*str1 = ' ';
++str1;

while (*str2 != '\0') {
    *str1 = *str2;
    str1++, str2++;
}

*str1 = '\0';
//printf("Concatenated String:\n");
//puts(conc);
dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "%s", conc);
return conc;

}
```

Try 3:

```
 char *prefixAry[2];
char *prefix = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(prefixAry) + 1);//+1 for the zero-terminator;
             *prefix = '\0';
             strcat(prefix, prefixAry[0]); //any value set
             strcat(prefix, prefixAry[1]); //any value set
             dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "-----Prefix : %s", prefix);
```

Am i doing right way ? Please help.

Actually i am parsing frames which comes from BLE chip. i have to decode it and get information then display it on UI. so choose array.

checkout my other issue if any different approch will appply:[ISSUE1](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/forums/native-application-development/read-write-value-custom-ble-chip.-native-wear-3.0?langredirect=1)

Thanks in advance.
Regards.

Answer (score 3):

### Concerning your try 1

Given that `finalFrame` is pointer array, these declarations and their initializers are fine:

> ```
>   char *id1 = finalFrame[6]; //0
>   char *id0 = finalFrame[7]; //3
> ```

but they do not appear to go with the formats in these print statements:

> ```
>   dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "id0 : %d", id0); // output: id1 : 0 
>   dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "id1 : %d", id1); // output: id1 : 3
> ```

Supposing that `dlog_print()` uses `printf`'s format string language, if you mean to print the values of the pointers themselves then you should use the `%p` field descriptor, not `%d`.  If you mean to print the contents of the character arrays to which they point (assuming them to be null-terminated) then you would use `%s`.  Using `%d` produces undefined behavior, but I'm prepared to speculate that the fact that the first `dlog_print()` outputs "0" indicates that `id0`'s value is a null pointer, and the fact that the second outputs "3" suggests that `id1`'s value is probably not a valid pointer.

If `id0` and `id1` were valid pointers to null-terminated character arrays, then the rest of try 1 would be just fine, but the fact that you get a crash on the next line:

> ```
>    if((idP = (char *)malloc(strlen(id0) + strlen(id1) + 1)) != NULL){ // appcrash here
> ```

tends to support the hypothesis that one or both of your pointers are invalid.

### Concerning try 2

This relies on there being enough unused space in the array pointed to by the first argument to accommodate the contents of the string to which the second points, plus the space you insert between (the terminator is already accounted for if the argument indeed points to a null-terminated string).  When that condition is satisfied, and the arguments are in fact valid pointers to null-terminated strings in the first place, it should work fine.

### Concerning try 3

Given this declaration:

> ```
> char *prefixAry[2];
> ```

... this allocation attempt is incorrect:

> ```
> char *prefix = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(prefixAry) + 1);//+1 for the zero-terminator;
> ```

In the first place, `prefixAry` is not initialized.  If it has file scope then its elements will be initialized to null pointers by default; otherwise, its initial value is indeterminate.  You cannot use it like that for your purpose, so let us move on by supposing that it was initialiized:

```
char *prefixAry[2] = { "one", "two" };
```

That still does not save the allocation, however, because it depends on `strlen(prefixAry)`.  The argument to `strlen()` must be a pointer to a null-terminated array of `char`, and that's not what you are providing.  Nor would `sizeof()` be right, either, for it would get you the combined size of two *pointers*, whereas you need the size of the data to which they point.

To rescue this, you would need something like

```
 char *prefix = malloc(strlen(prefixAry[0]) + strlen(prefixAry[1]) + 1);
```

Note that `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, and that this allocation is now equivalent to the one in your "Try 1".

Having allocated enough space, the `strcat()`-based approach in this alternative is viable.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for clear out doubt but still not work with Try1. please see my question on Tizen Community [link](https://developer.tizen.org/forums/native-application-development/failed-concate-pointer-variables#none)

Comment: @MTTeam, I will not refer to your posts on some other site; any information on which an answer here should be based must be presented in the question *here*.  There is nothing more that can be said based on the information currently provided.  If you take nothing else from this answer, you should take this: the main problem with your Try 1 is likely not with the code you've posted, but rather with the data it is operating on, i.e. the values you are assigning to `id0` and `id1`, and the data, if any, to which they point.